# Where to get Chibi Maker with complete customizable movement?

Tags: animation, gif, tools, free, character

I found out that Chibi Character Maker online is the best tool i ever known.
Such as these list:

[1) ChibiMaker](https://www.chibimaker.net)

[2) GamesGames](http://www.gamesgames.com/game/chibi-maker)

But none of them are making the chibi character has a movement, such as fighting, laughing, etc....

Does anyone ever found the online-resource tool that easy to be customized?

Comment: Making even quite blocky animations need good tools and much work. One example: https://cartoonsmart.com/?portfolio=how-to-animate-a-chibi-style-archer-character-in-adobe-animate-basics-tips-and-tools.  Making plausible elastic body movements is possible with astronomical amount of talent & skill or by applying detailed motion modelling + development software which uses it and still plenty of talent & skill and work is needed. I guess nobody who has created such software armament wants to limit it to one character style.

Comment: (continued) It's well possible that EA's Sims have add-on kits which make what you wanted. I do not have such. For movie makers there are software which warp 2D or 3D characters to match with the movements of a real human. The movements are recorded with one or more high resolution movie cameras and the actors have special clothes which have easily recognizable calibration points. Games utilize modelled muscles, soft tissues, bones, joints, cloth material properties and motion physics. Realistic muscle actions for plausible motion and face expression are estimated from recorded real actors

Comment: What's a "chibi"?

Comment: A chibi is a miniature anime avatar and sorry but no i haven't found any animations.